# HTML5 Audio player with multiple files (random)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Is it possible that the standard html5 player play all files randomly form a specific directory like `../mp3/`?

A jQuery audio player is ok too... but I didn't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to **jlplayer**
jlPlayer – A Fully Customizable HTML5 Audio Player With jQuery And jQuery UI

Features Include:

- 100% opensource and FREE! No ads, tricks, gimmicks, or pitches. :)
- Play, pause, <<, >>, volume, and progress.
- Create a playlist of any length, including titles, and descriptions.
- Loop, auto-advance, auto-start, **shuffle**.
- Fully customizable using CSS, and/or the jQuery UI Framework ThemeRoller.
- Add multiple music source files for increased cross-browser support (mp3, ogg, wav).

[**Reference**](http://jasonlau.biz/home/jquery/jlplayer)

Comment: The problem is that I need to enter a fixed path for each mp3 file.
I want to enter one path like "../mp3/" because the joomla user will upload the mp3 files in this directory...

shuffle is the wrong way because for this i have to enter a particular path for each mp3 file.

Comment: all your files stored in `../mp3/` folder ? and you want play random from this folder ?

Comment: yes exactly... thats why i have to enter only this path because i dont know the name of the mp3 files wich the joomla user will upload next time... it should playy all mp3 files from this folder randomly

Comment: this is a bug that all users have same folder. how you detect specific user's files?

Comment: in jlplayer you have `<a href="audio/JasonLau.biz - Gone.ogg">ogg</a> <a href="audio/JasonLau.biz - Gone.mp3">mp3</a>` on each `li` tag. so you can put custom url to custom file in `href` property of `<a` tag.

Comment: i dont know the name of the mp3 files so i cant enter custom url to each <a tag... the customer will upload his mp3 files to the "../mp3/" folder... something like  <a href="../mp3/*.mp3"> ?

Comment: your question is how to use player with multi file and random play effect. but I think your problem is where and how to store and retrieve mp3 files !

Comment: if you have folder then you can read all files of a folder with specific type for example `mp3` with php read folder content commands. but in this solution you cant show own user files. this will show all mp3 files located in folder

Comment: sorry if I've made ​​my question understandable.
First, I need a html5 or jquery audio player because flash does not work on ipad.
This player is should have a play button and a volume control.
This player will now play all mp3 files randomly from one folder .
The names of the mp3 files are not known as these, the customer will upload the mp3 files via Joomla Admin Center. This means it will someday again an additional mp3 file to upload. This should be played without enter a specific path again for the new mp3 file.

Comment: ok I think this meet all of your needs [https://github.com/josephrmoore/mp3player](https://github.com/josephrmoore/mp3player)

Comment: Yes perfect!!.. But this script dont work on Safari so i cant use it :/